# MySQL - Export list of Family Names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a MySQL database in the open-source application ChurchCRM. (schema available here: https://github.com/ChurchCRM/CRM/wiki/default.schema)

I am trying to get a specific SQL query to work. I want to get a CONCAT of the head of a Family in the format: Family Name, Head and Spouse.

I can currently get the query to give me the Family Name for every Person. I can also get the first name of the Head of Household tacked on after the Family Name, but when I try to grab the Spouse, the query breaks. I can only assume it is due to not every Head having a Spouse, but it doesn't break on a Person not having a Family. Does anyone have a suggestion?

The below query works and gives me 'FamilyName, Head and Head'. If I change `WHERE spouse.per_fmr_ID = 1 to 2`, it breaks. per_fmr_ID is an identifier INT for Family Role which will be 1 for Head of Household, 2 for Spouse, 3 for Child, 4 for Other.

```
SELECT
CONCAT(per.per_FirstName,' ',per.per_LastName) as 'Name',
CONCAT(fam.fam_Name,', ',
  ( SELECT head.per_FirstName
    FROM person_per AS head
    WHERE head.per_fam_ID = per.per_fam_ID && head.per_fmr_ID =1
  ),' and ',
  ( SELECT spouse.per_FirstName
    FROM person_per AS spouse
    WHERE spouse.per_fmr_ID = 1 && spouse.per_fam_ID = per.per_fam_ID
  )
) as 'Family Name'
FROM person_per AS per
LEFT JOIN family_fam AS fam ON per.per_fam_ID = fam.fam_ID
```

[image: Example output showing suggested COALESCE]

showing successful run when Spouse search is doing Head again.  As mentioned above if the second subquery checks for per_fmr_ID = 2, the query fails to run.

Comment: As the schema gives no clue as to what `per_fmr_id` means, and as you include no example data, this is close to impossible to answer. To improve the chances of people being able to help, I recommend reading the guide on Minimal Reproducible Examples.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/Minimal-Reproducible-example. (You should also clearly explain what "breaks" means. Error message? Unexpected output? In which case example data becomes key again...)

Comment: I had to infer it out myself and added it to the question.

Comment: As for example data and error, I am not able to give the error on this as this is being run within a query form on the ChurchCRM app, rather than a command line.  It does not give an error but simply does not process the query.

Comment: Is this in MySQL 8.0 or MySQL 5.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "multiple spouses" is the only cause of failure, and if you're on MySQL 8.0, then I'd use `GROUP_CONCAT()`...

```
CONCAT(
  fam.fam_Name,
  ', ',
  (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(per_firstname ORDER BY per_fmr_id SEPARATOR ' and ')
      FROM person_per AS heads
     WHERE heads.per_fam_ID = per.per_fam_ID
  )
)
  AS family_name
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Tried this approach by encapsulating the subquery with COALESCE, but it is the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: @owltrkr - can you reverse engineer anything? Can you check that there is definitely only one spouse (`per_fmr_id = 2`) per family? If you're getting multiple then the query would crash.

Comment: There is ONE instance in this dataset where there are 2 spouses. I found that while trying to troubleshoot this.
UPDATE, That was it! The extra spouse in that family was meant to be a child. Corrected that and the query works.  Thank you.

Comment: @owltrkr MySQL 8.0 or MySQL 5.x?

Comment: @owltrkr Then it may crash again. If you have MySQL 8.0 then you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to gather any number of other names, rather than having a query that only works if the data is "correct".